# Display String in TextView after user input in another class

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to pass a String from a class (UserInput) to Main Activity and display it in a TextView. User is supposed to press a button in Main Activity, which calls UserInput and enter a String. Using Shared Preferences, I managed to pass the String over, but could not get it to display in the TextView.

I realized that the getSharedPreference and setText part was done before the class was started, resulting in the TextView not being updated after returning from UserInput and I have no idea how to solve this issue. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

## Main Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tvCode;
Button btnCode, btnClear;
TextInputLayout textInputMessage;
String preferenceFileName, preferenceKey, retreivedCodeString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvCode = findViewById(R.id.textViewCode);
    btnCode = findViewById(R.id.buttonCode);
    btnClear = findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
    textInputMessage = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutMessage);
    preferenceFileName = "PreferenceFile";
    preferenceKey = "CodeKey";


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    retreivedCodeString = sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceKey,"");
    tvCode.setText(retreivedCodeString);

    btnCode.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonClear:
            //method
            break;
        case R.id.buttonCode:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserInput.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            retreivedCodeString = sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceKey,"");
            tvCode.setText(retreivedCodeString);
            break;
    }

}
```

## UserInput code

```
public class UserInput extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
String userInputCode, preferenceFileName, preferenceKey;
TextInputLayout subTextInputLayoutCode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.code);

    subTextInputLayoutCode = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutCode);
    Button btnOk = findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
    Button btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    preferenceFileName = "PreferenceFile";
    preferenceKey = "CodeKey";

    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonOk:
            if (!validateCode()){
                return;
            }
            userInputCode = subTextInputLayoutCode.getEditText().getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(preferenceKey,userInputCode);
            editor.apply();
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonCancel:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone will definitely post the solutions, but I would seriously suggest to move to Fragments for the use case you are trying to address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Way 1:**

use below code in `onResume` method of your `MainActivity`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
retreivedCodeString = sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceKey,"");
tvCode.setText(retreivedCodeString);
```

**Way 2:**

start your `UserInput` activity for result (`startActivitForResult(intent, 123)`)

and finish your `UserInput` activity using below code

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
finish()
```

in your main activity override `onActivityResultMethode` like below

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(requestCode == 123 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(preferenceFileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
         retreivedCodeString = sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceKey,"");
         tvCode.setText(retreivedCodeString);
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

**Way 3: (without sharedPreferences )**

start your `UserInput` activity for result (`startActivitForResult(intent, 123)`)

and finish your `UserInput` activity using below code

```
Intent i = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("inputText", YOUR_INPUT_TEXT);
i.putExtras(b);
setResult(123, i)
finish()
```

in your main activity override `onActivityResultMethode` like below

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(requestCode == 123 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
         tvCode.setText(data.getExtras().getString("inputText",""));
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```